# How to know when a user disconnects from a Faye channel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, faye

I'm trying to use Faye to build a simple chat room with Rails, and host it on heroku. So far I was able to make the Faye server run, and get instant messaging to work. The crucial lines of code that I'm using are:

**Javascript file launched when the page loads:**

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client(<< My Feye server on Heoku here >>);
  faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

---

**create.js.erb, triggered when the user sends a message**

```
<% broadcast "/messages/new" do %>
  $("#chat").append("<%= j render(@message) %>");
<% end %>
```

---

Everything is working fine, but now I would like to notify when a user disconnects from the chat. **How should I do this?**

I already looked in the [Faye's website about monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html), but it's not clear where should I put that code.

Answer (score 6):

Event monitoring goes in your rackup file. Here is an example I'm using in production:

```
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(mount: '/faye', timeout: 25)

server.bind(:disconnect) do |client_id|
  puts "Client #{client_id} disconnected"
end

run server
```

Of course you can do whatever you like in the block you pass to `#bind`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this makes my app crashing, both locally and on heroku. The error just says that the method "bind" does not exists: 'config.ru:24:in `block in <main>: undefined method `bind' for #<Faye::RackAdapter:0x007fe95ce6cb00> (NoMethodError)'

Comment: Check the versions of the Faye gems that you're using. The code above definitely works with faye 0.8.2 and faye-websocket 0.4.5.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to bind to the `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` events instead of the `disconnect` event. Read the word of warning on the bottom of the [faye monitoring docs](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html).

This has worked well for me:

```
server.bind(:subscribe) do |client_id|
  # code to execute
  # puts "Client #{client_id} connected"
end

server.bind(:unsubscribe) do |client_id|
  # code to execute
  # puts "Client #{client_id} disconnected"
end
```

I also recommend using the [private pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) gem - this will help secure your faye app.

Comment: can you publish to a given channel? I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/mariusbutuc/5477442) but I only [get timeouts](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/76) `[ERROR] [Faye::RackAdapter] Timeout::Error`